# Use define between systemverilog and DPI-C

Tags: system-verilog-dpi

In systemverilog  sv_define.vh

```
`define A_MODULE_ENABLE
//`define B_MODULE_ENABLE
```

In C              c_define.h

```
#define A_MODULE_ENABLE
//#define B_MODULE_ENABLE
```

Since syntax for "define" is different between systemverilog and C. 
If I want to config ENABLE, I have to modify those two files, that would sometimes be troublesome. How can I just define them in a single file and  include it ? Thanks a lot.

My imagination: my top.sv and top.c would include the same file: c_sy_define.vh
The content would be:

```
__SV__
    `define A_MODULE_ENABLE
    //`define B_MODULE_ENABLE
__C__
    #define A_MODULE_ENABLE
    //#define B_MODULE_ENABLE
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeap.  This will probably work.   Never try it though.

```
#ifndef COMPILE_IN_C
`define A_MODULE_ENABLE
#endif

`ifndef COMPILE_IN_SV
#define A_MODULE_ENABLE
`endif
```

Wen you compile the header file, make sure you add "-define COMPILE_IN_SV" in ncvlog (say you use Cadence), and add "-DCOMPILE_IN_C" in gcc.